# C# How can I store class constructor in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to create an object of a different class in different situations. So I decided to use dictionary. I want to see something like that:

```
var Object = new myDictionary["someString"];
```

where myDictionary["someString"] leads to a class constructor. By the way, all classes in this dict have the same parent class.

Comment: You should research the Factory Pattern.

Comment: This sounds a little like an XY problem, can't you use dependency injection, or as Dai suggest, the factory pattern?

Comment: Agree with Dai.. also note that constructors are not normal methods. The constructor itself cannot be passed by reference or stored anywhere. In this case I would put *factory* class instances in the dictionary, for each class produced. The factory class is then invoked as var Object = myDictionary["someString"].Create(...) or myDictionary["someString"].CreateSomeString(...)

Comment: @Goodies It is unfortunate that we can't bind a constructor to a `Func<T>`. Grumble.

Comment: .. which is a good reason to use factory classes in C#. I think it is a bad idea anyway to put function pointers in a dictionary. With that, all function stored need to have the same arguments, because the function type Func<T> is to be included in the dictionary definition. If you use factory classes, a single factory class can provide one or more Create() methods for several different objects. With a single function pointer, the result must be casted, a factory.Create() does not need to be casted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) of [`Func`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-5.0)'s creating instances:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<BaseClass>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Func<BaseClass>>
{
   {"BaseClass", () => new BaseClass()}
};

var x = myDictionary["BaseClass"]();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly for my case.